# Last year Data From Current Year in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I should project the last year data based on Current year and current period selection .For example 
YEAR :2018 Quarter:Q1 Period:P1 If I select these value as filters i should get previous year data(i.e 2017) for same quarters(Q1) and periods(P1) ,I used SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ,PARALLELPERIOD but not working looking for some other formula Please help me out to solve in power bi .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SELECTEDVALUE function. For example
    DATE(SELECTEDVALUE(TimeCalendarTable[CalendarYear])-1;MONTH(TODAY());DAY(TODAY()))

gives you same day and month as today, last year. 
Try SELECTEDVALUE and let me know how it went.